# How to get same column width using Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a way to get same column width on different rows using Flexbox ?

I would like to have the same width for `cell--id` (The width must have the width of the largest `cell--id`).

Example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell cell--id">1</div>
    <div class="cell">Test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell cell--id">2222</div>
    <div class="cell">Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
<style>
   .row { display: flex }
</style>
```

Comment: at a glance, this seems like you want `display: table-row` instead of `flex`

Comment: are your rows all going to be the same height? If so, you could swap to column-major - i.e. put your column `div`s outside your row `div`s

Comment: Here's someone attempting to solve this, but he basically manually makes some columns wider than others - if this would work for you you could use something similar, but if not I think you'll need to go with one of the other options I mentioned http://inlehmansterms.net/2014/10/11/responsive-tables-with-flexbox/

Comment: Just set the same width for the columns (`.cell`).

Comment: @starikovs how do you know what that width should be, without using javascript? Should probably have included "assuming you don't want to do it in javascript" somewhere I guess.

Comment: Why don't you use a `<table>`?

Answer (score 8):

You're basically describing a table, so you should probably be using table layout instead, e.g.

```css
.row { display: table-row }
.cell { display: table-cell }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell cell--id">1</div>
    <div class="cell">Test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell cell--id">2222</div>
    <div class="cell">Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you're dead set on flexbox, I see two options:

1. if your rows are going to be the same height, you could swap to column-major - i.e. put your column divs outside your row divs
2. manually manage the size of the columns, similar to this: http://inlehmansterms.net/2014/10/11/responsive-tables-with-flexbox/

But really, I think you want table layout.

Comment: Thanks, but no solution with Flexbox?

Comment: I'm very slow to say 'no' to questions like that. However, I'm also a believer in 'if it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, use table layout'

Comment: These are 2 flexbox containers and you want same width in both: +1 for using CSS table instead where columns can't have a different width so problem solved. If you've other constraints (for example in different resolutions) and want to use flexbox, then see the `flex` shorthand _property_ (not the value of `display` property but the property `flex`) and its 3 parts in [CSS tricks Flexbox cheatsheet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @FelipeAls there isn't anything in there that will solve the original problem though, is there?

Answer (score 6):

Your need to think:

- in rows of one or more columns => row is the **flexible** container
- or in columns of one or more rows => column is the **flexible** container
- the contents are **flexed** items (and can be nested flexible containers)

In your case you need to give .row a width and make flexbox split the cells evenly over the row:

```
.row  { display: flex; width: 300px }
.cell { flex: 1 } /* each cell width will be: available space divided by the number of cells */
```

Ok, here's the POC:

```css
        .row    { display: flex; width: 500px }
        .cell   { flex: 1 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell cell--id">1</div>
    <div class="cell">Test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell cell--id">2222</div>
    <div class="cell">Test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell cell--id">2222222222222</div>
    <div class="cell">Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice tip for flex: 1